# zf 1: how to render only the widget of an element?

Tags: zend-framework

I have a form that i have instantiated in the controller and now i want to render in the view.

Is there any way to render the fields without the label (only the input, select.. html tags)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$formelement = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('Name'); // _Textarea etc.
$formElement->setDecorators(array('ViewHelper'));
```

This decorator will render only tag , etc